# Find number of unique values of a parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

Given a parameter pack with variadic arguments, how can one find the number of unique values in the pack. I am looking for something along the lines of

```
no_of_uniques<0,1,2,1,2,2>::value // should return 3
```

My rudimentary implementation looks something this

```
template <size_t ... all>
struct no_of_uniques;
// this specialisation exceeds -ftemplate-depth as it has no terminating condition
template <size_t one, size_t ... all>
struct no_of_uniques<one,all...> {
    static const size_t value = no_of_uniques<one,all...>::value;
};
template <size_t one, size_t two, size_t three>
struct no_of_uniques<one,two,three> {
    static const size_t value = (one==two && one==three && two==three) ? 1:
                                (one!=two && two==three) ? 2:
                                (one==two && one!=three) ? 2:
                                (one==three && two!=three) ? 2: 3;
};
template <size_t one, size_t two>
struct no_of_uniques<one,two> {
    static const size_t value = one==two ? 1: 2;
};
template <size_t one>
struct no_of_uniques<one> {
    static const size_t value = 1;
};
```

Here, I have specialised for up to three arguments but understandably the code grows exponentially with the number of arguments. I would like to have a `meta` solution for this using solely `STL` and no third party libraries like `Boost.MPL`.

A similar question albeit in the context of checking unique types, rather than finding number of unique values of parameter pack can be found here:

[Check variadic templates parameters for uniqueness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18986560/2750396)

In the process of finding the number of unique values of a parameter pack, we might need to sort the pack first, and an excellent implementation of that is provided in this other question

[Quick sort at compilation time using C++11 variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188182/quick-sort-at-compilation-time-using-c11-variadic-templates)

Comment: is the parameter pack always ints?

Comment: Yes. It is a homogeneous pack.

Comment: As for (runtime) algorithm, sort, unique and size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple O(n^2) way to do it

```
template <size_t...>
struct is_unique : std::integral_constant<bool, true> {};

template <size_t T, size_t U, size_t... VV>
struct is_unique<T, U, VV...> : std::integral_constant<bool, T != U && is_unique<T, VV...>::value> {};

template <size_t...>
struct no_unique : std::integral_constant<size_t, 0> {};

template <size_t T, size_t... UU>
struct no_unique<T, UU...> : std::integral_constant<size_t, is_unique<T, UU...>::value + no_unique<UU...>::value> {};
```

So using your example:

```
no_unique<0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2>::value; // gives 3
```

Answer (score 6):

Most of this is machinery I already wrote for [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36467664/2756719), stripped of the "counting" part.

A pack with a `sizeof` shortcut:

```
template<class... Ts> struct pack { 
    static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};
```

Add a type to a pack of types, but only if it doesn't exist already:

```
template<class T, class PT> struct do_push;
template<class T, class...Ts>
struct do_push<T, pack<Ts...>>{
   using type = std::conditional_t<std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Ts, T>...>,
        pack<Ts...>,
        pack<T, Ts...>
        >;
};
template<class T, class PT> using push = typename do_push<T, PT>::type;
```

Now make a pack of unique types:

```
template<class P, class PT = pack<> >
struct unique_types_imp { using type = PT; };

template<class PT, class T, class... Ts>
struct unique_types_imp <pack<T, Ts...>, PT>
        : unique_types_imp <pack<Ts...>, push<T, PT>> {};

template<class P>
using unique_types = typename unique_types_imp<P>::type;
```

Finally:

```
template<size_t S>
using size_constant = std::integral_constant<size_t, S>;

template<size_t... all>
struct no_of_uniques{
     static constexpr size_t value = unique_types<pack<size_constant<all>...>>::size;
};
```

Comment: Looking at this, I wonder if it is possible to also get the unique values, instead of just the number of unique values, as you are just pushing to the pack. For instance, have a `struct unique` that forwards the pack of `<1,2,3,2,1>` to `<1,2,3>`?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_uniquel), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```cpp
template <size_t... Ns>
using no_of_uniques = mp_size<mp_unique<mp_list<mp_size_t<Ns>...>>>;
```

Following the same logic as described below. We lift the values into types, put them in a type list, get the unique types out of that, and then get the length.

---

I'll generalize to types - since metaprogramming works better in types. The algorithm for counting uniqueness is an empty argument list has 0 unique types, and a non-empty list has 1 unique type + the number of unique types in the tail of that list after having removed the initial type.

In fact, let's generalize further than that - let's write a metafunction that takes a list of types and returns the unique types in it. Once you have the unique types, it's easy to count them.

```
template <class... > struct typelist { };

template <class >
struct uniq;

template <class TL>
using uniq_t = typename uniq<TL>::type;

template <>
struct uniq<typelist<>> {
    using type = typelist<>;
};

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct uniq<typelist<T, Ts...>>
    : concat<typelist<T>, uniq_t<filter_out_t<T, typelist<Ts...>>>>
{ };
```

Now we just need to fill in `concat` and `filter_out_t`. The latter is basically a glorified `concat` anyway:

```
template <class... > struct concat;
template <> struct concat<> { using type = typelist<>; };

template <class... Ts>
struct concat<typelist<Ts...>> {
    using type = typelist<Ts...>;
};

template <class... Ts, class... Us, class... Args>
struct concat<typelist<Ts...>, typelist<Us...>, Args...>
: concat<typelist<Ts..., Us...>, Args...>
{ };

template <class T, class TL>
struct filter_out;

template <class T, class TL>
using filter_out_t = typename filter_out<T, TL>::type;

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct filter_out<T, typelist<Ts...>>
    : concat<
        std::conditional_t<std::is_same<T, Ts>::value, typelist<>, typelist<Ts>>...
        >
{ };
```

Now, given a list of types, we can figure out the unique ones. To backport to the original problem, we just need a a size metafunction:

```
template <size_t N>
using size_t_ = std::integral_constant<size_t, N>;

template <class > struct length;
template <class T> using length_t = typename length<T>::type;
template <class... Ts>
struct length<typelist<Ts...>>
: size_t_<sizeof...(Ts)>
{ };
```

And then wrap everything up in one alias:

```
template <size_t... Ns>
using no_of_uniques = length_t<uniq_t<typelist<size_t_<Ns>...>>>;
```

Comment: don't forget to convert the input arguments (which are size_t's) to integral_values:

`template<std::size_t...Is>
  constexpr std::size_t uniques()
  {
    return no_of_uniques< std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>... >::value;
  };`

Comment: The comment was written more for the benefit of readers than writers :)

Comment: @Barry, Can't get your solution to work. Seemingly I am doing something incorrect. The empty `no_of_uniques<>` and one argument `no_of_uniques<size_t>` work, but as soon as I do more than one argument like `no_of_uniques<2,3>` I get the following error under `clang 3.6.1`:  `implicit instantiation of undefined template 'concat<std::conditional<false, typelist<>, typelist<std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 3> > > >` .

Comment: Huh, didn't notice that this was a `c++1z` solution. Would it be possible to backport this to `c++11`. Correct me if I am wrong, but I reckon `std::conditional_t` is the only `c++1z` feature here.

Comment: @romeric There are no C++1z features in that code. Just one type alias which is easy to write in C++11.

Comment: Yes, was talking about that. Got it working. Many thanks.

Comment: @Barry This is still O(n^2) due to looking up T in the tail on each element though, right?

Comment: @ofo Yes it is.