# Pass/forward a selected number of parameter pack to another function

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

Coming from this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37150354/2750396) on finding the number of unique values of a parameter pack, has made me think, if it is feasible to pass/forward a selected number of variadic parameter pack to another function or to return them, for instance, assume we have a `struct` that takes a homogeneous pack

```
template<size_t ... Rest>
struct my_struct;
```

I would like to have a function `foo` that takes this parameter pack and returns another `struct` with unique values of the parameter pack passed to it, something like

```
template<size_t N, size_t ... Rest>
my_struct<uniques<N,Rest...>> foo(const my_struct<N,Rest...> &a) {
// do stuff
}
```

As an example:

```
my_struct<0,5,2,0,4,2> a;
my_struct<0,5,2,4> b = foo(a);
```

Sorting the values, is not of any interest here. Is this functionality possible to achieve using only the standard library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap `uniques` in another metafunction. Just building off of my [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37150576/2069064):

```
template <class T, template <T...> class Z>
struct quote_c {
    template <class... Ts>
    using apply = Z<Ts::value...>;
};

template <class MFC, class TL>
struct apply_typelist;

template <class MFC, class TL>
using apply_typelist_t = typename apply_typelist<MFC, TL>::type;


template <class MFC, class... Ts>
struct apply_typelist<MFC, typelist<Ts...>> {
    using type = typename MFC::template apply<Ts...>;
};
```

Now we have a metafunction class version of `my_struct`, and a metafunction that takes a metafunction class and a typelist and jams them together.

So now it's just:

```
template <class T, T... Vals>
using typelist_c = typelist<std::integral_constant<T, Vals>...>;

template <size_t N,
          size_t ... Rest,
          class R = apply_typelist_t<quote_c<size_t, my_struct>,
                        uniq_t<typelist_c<size_t, N, Rest...>>>
          >
R foo(const my_struct<N,Rest...> &a) {
    // ...
}
```

---

To work through your example of `<0,5,2,0,4,2>`.

1. First, we wrap all those numbers into types to get a `typelist<0i,5i,2i,0i,4i,2i>` (I'm just using `i` as shorthand to mean that it's a `std::integral_constant`).
2. Next we wrap that in `uniq_t`, which produces `typelist<0i,5i,2i,4i>`.
3. Next, we pass that into `apply_typelist` which gives us the type `quote_c<size_t, my_struct>::apply<0i, 5i, 2i, 4i>`
4. Which itself is an alias for `my_struct<0, 5, 2, 4>`, as desired.

Comment: I think the bit in the signature for function `foo `should be modified to read `quote_c<size_t, my_struct>` instead of just `quote_c<my_struct>`.

Comment: @romeric Thanks, fixed.