# Removing dependence on type ordering in variadic template classes

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a class, which boils down to this:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
class Stuff
{
   std::vector<std::variant<std::vector<Ts>...>> v_data;
}
```

Ts are unique types. Now as far as I understand, excepting for the indices there is no difference between `std::variant<A, B>` and `std::variant<B, A>`, which means that with some care Stuff should also be order-insensitive. Furthermore, since variants can take only one state at a time there should be no problem in treating `Stuff<A>` as `Stuff<A, B>`, as long as one doesn't go asking for data of type B from this instance.

Problem is, how do I allow such a conversion? I tried writing a conversion operator:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
template <typename ...Us>
Stuff<Ts...>::operator const Stuff<Us...>&() const
{
  /* some assert ensuring that Us is at least as wide as Ts */
  return &(*this);
}
```

plus a few other versions with static_cast etc, but they fail to compile with some variation of invalid casting of this.

The idea is to store references (_wrapper) to instances of Stuff inside a container and operated on together, and what I don't know what should T be in `std::reference_wrapper<T>` that fits all these Stuffs.

A few other things I considered:

- having all Stuffs inherit from a non-template type and store references to that: works, but some Stuff member functions takes lambda as arguments and so need to be templates, which can't be virtual
- store instead a variant of all possible variations of Stuff references: I don't know how to "explode" the type list ie to go from `Stuff<A, B>` to `Stuff<A>, Stuff<B>, Stuff<A, B>, Stuff<B, A>`

Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:
Apologies for editing/bumping, but let me elaborate a bit more what I mentioned in the comments.

In [Permutation P(N,R) of types in compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465889/permutation-pn-r-of-types-in-compile-time) there is a working implementation for type explosion. This would fit my purpose if it can be extend in two ways:

1- A way to "sum" the `PermutationN<N, P<A, B, C>>`s from 1 to N. Haven't tried to actually do this yet, due to the difficulty in achieving the next extension, but it's probably related to `tuple_cat` somehow

2- instead of wrapping it all under the same wrapper like `P<P<A, B>, P<B, A>>` one can use different wrappers say, `T<U<A, B>, U<B, A>>`. I tried doing this myself, but since the wrappers I have in mind can't be empty, while the machinery relies on `P<>`, I need to somehow translate from `P` to `T` and `U`, which I haven't been very successful at

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816579/assign-varianta-b-c-from-variantc-b not a full answer but may be a start

Comment: To an extent I think that particular aspect is solved, since if we know the super- and sub-variant types then std::get(_if)<T> handle the problem fine. It's the transferring of types that is the problem I'm facing.

FWIW for the second option, I checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465889/permutation-pn-r-of-types-in-compile-time to implement it, but my metaprogramming skills are not good enough to adapt it to my needs.

Comment: *"there is no difference between `std::variant<A, B>` and `std::variant<B, A>`"* I'm not sure what you mean by that. Perhaps they behave similarly, but they are distinct types, and there's no implicit conversion from one to the other. It should be possible to write a function that manufactures a value of `std::variant<B, A>` given `std::variant<A, B>` (that is, copies the data from one to the other), but I don't see how to write a function that manufactures a `std::variant<B, A>&` reference  - there's no object for that reference to refer to.

Comment: I agree that they're distinct types, as one can easily see with std::is_same_v. However, my point is that these variants are members of classes whose methods can be written such that the type ordering is irrelevant, which is why I wanted a way to be able to treat instances of and references to Stuff<A, B> and Stuff<B, A> etc in the same way, such as putting them into a container.

See also second option and comment above about taking a variant of all possible Stuff variations, in which case the problem reduces to implementing such a type explosion.